# How can I calculate the combinations of items across multiple arrays?

Tags: combinations

If I have multiple arrays of items, how can I calculate the combination of collections that are possible?

Ex:

```
a = [Red, Green, Blue]
b = [Small, Medium, Large, X-Large]
c = [Round, Square]
```

I'd like to know how many ways these groupings can be combined, ex:

```
[Red, Small, Round]
[Red, Small, Square]
[Red, Medium, Round]
[Red, Medium, Square]
...
```

And so on...

There could be more than just these 3 arrays.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Counting Principle](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/sequences/counting.html). Basically, you multiply the number of elements in each array.